# Python OSError Cannot open resource

Tags: python

This is my file structure:

```
main
 |
 | - generate.py
 | - car.png
```

Inside the generate.py file, I'm building PDF document using ReportLab library, as follows:

```
def generatePDF():
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(base_dir)
    story = []
    # ... adding paragraphs of text
    car = [['Renault', Image('car.png'), 'Description']]
    table = Table(car, colWidths=100, rowHeights=50)
    story.append(table)
    doc.build(story)
```

Running this code raise the following error:

```
OSError at /car/
fileName='car.png' identity=[ImageReader@0x4563bb0 filename='car.png'] Cannot open resource "car.png"
```

Why is this? Can you see what I'm doing wrong here?

If I remove the image from table, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a core Python error but it is raised by ReportLab. The error says that ReportLab cannot find the `car.png` file. This is probably caused by the current directory not being what you expect. If you give a filename without a full path, the file is searched in the current working directory of the process, not in the directory of the Python file. You should use:

```
car = [['Renault', Image(os.path.join(base_dir, 'car.png')), 'Description']]
```